# The influence of a temperature gradient on the growth of dendrites in a solid liquid interface

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, diffusion

Not sure if this is the correct place to ask...

My book states that, for a Solid Liquid interface in which the liquid has an increasing positive temperature gradient (increasing temperatures in liquid region) that "The temperature gradient in the liquid ahead of the nodule will increase while that in the solid decreases, consequently more heat will be conducted into the protruding solid and less away so that the growth rate [of the protrusion/nodule] will decrease below that of the planar region.

On a related note, when the temperature gradient is negative in the liquid region, " the liquid becomes even more negative.  Therefore heat is removed more effectively from the tip of the protrusion than from the surrounding regions allowing it to grow preferentially".

My question is, why does more heat being conducted into the solid cause it to become planar?  Similarly, why does removing heat from the tip of the protrusion make it grow faster?